# Sometimes widgets not rendering in production builds

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Sometimes the widget doesn't render properly. This only happens on the release build irrespective of the platform OS. Not only texts, sometimes other widgets like container, images won't get rendered either. This "blank state" occurs irrespective of the app's life cycle, meaning this happens both when the app is in the background and comes foreground or opened freshly. I can work around in the app normally without any issues but can't see any widgets which I'm supposed to see. We found there are multiple rebuilds happening in the stateful widget which is responsible for the checking and routing the users according to their login status.

Anything wrong in this method?

//initializations (state variable)

```
Widget widgetToRender = Splash();
var _firestore;
bool isLoading = false;
StreamSubscription userProfileSubscription;
```

//initalize function

```
void _intialise(BuildContext context) async {
if (isLoading) {
  return;
}
_firestore = Provider.of<FirestoreService>(context);
userProfileSubscription = _firestore.userProfile.listen((userProfile) {
  this.setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
    widgetToRender = App();
  });
});
}
```

//build method

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
if (widget.userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
  if (widget.userSnapshot.hasData) {
    _intialise(context);
  } else {
     setState((){
widgetToRender = AuthLanding();
})
  }
}

return widgetToRender;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu Agreed, this part definitely needs refactoring, but this issue I'm specifically having, could it be because of that?

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is a declarative framework.
You're going against it when you declare widgets like this:

```
Widget widgetToRender = Splash();
```

Also, you shouldn't call methods that execute imperative code from your build method:

```
_intialise(context);
```

My suggestion is to completely remove this code:

```
Widget widgetToRender = Splash();
var _firestore;
```

And rewrite things in a declarative manner. One way to do that is to use a `StreamBuilder`, and use its builder to return the widgets you want.

Addressing this may solve your rendering problems.

EDIT: step 1 would probably be to remove all imperative code and state variables in the build method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (widget.userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
    if (widget.userSnapshot.hasData) {
      return App();
    } else {
      return AuthLanding();
    }
  }
  return Scaffold(body: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

Comment: When you see a rendering issue like this (sometimes text only, sometimes other widgets), what is usually the culprit? When the app is in this state, it's still usable and doesn't hang or crash.
Is this a specific class of issue that is common?

Comment: we have followed your provider tutorials with a few changes. but we do have a StreamBuilder. 
https://gist.github.com/saigkl/42e16e66e798871074b9494c372fbdd4

Comment: https://gist.github.com/saigkl/d7092c9f3a1d6499838be8e59608a26b - this is the root of the app.
This calls the auth_gateway_builder.dart and the above-mentioned code is "AuthGateway".

Comment: I can't tell for sure and I don't have time to check your entire source code. I updated my answer with more info.

The screenshot you posted doesn't have much to do with the code you posted here. Rather something may be wrong in your `App` widget or descendant widgets.

Answer (score 0):

The load lag is because you are only working with widget.userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active you will need to add progress indicators as the response from firestore depends on the network status of the user. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: While this widget.userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active is false, I'm rendering the splash screen. Which is equivalent to your progress indicator. Still, the issue prevails.

Comment: where are you loading the strings from? is it from the database ??

Comment: I'm sorry friend, it looks like you need to take help from someone who is actually permitted to  see the code.